# Сдвигается фиксированный div при использовании fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

на сайте фиксированное меню, прижатое к верхней границе.

```
nav {
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
background: #ccc;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Для всплывающих окон используется fancybox.
При открытии окна фиксированное меню смещается 
вправо на ширину строки прокрутки.

Есть ли в fancybox какие-то параметры, которые можно передать скрипту,
отвечающие за отключение сдвига?

Если нет, то возможно есть другие решения?

Comment: Разве fancybox не создает всплывающее окно, которое не влияет на другие элементы страницы?

Comment: Создаёт, кроме блоков с position: fixed.

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит дать ссылку на рабочий пример воспроизводящий данный сдвиг.

Comment: Например, как на этом сайте: http://spas-gruz.ru/
Сдвигается верхнее меню при нажатии на ссылку ЗАЯВКА НА РАСЧЁТ СТОИМОСТИ (кнопка в футере).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/mqj2xw9z/

Comment: В вашем примере если содержимое всплывающего она больше, чем высота окна браузера, то окно уже не фиксировано, и начинает ездить.

Comment: Если фиксированному блоку вместо width: 100%; задать точную ширину экран, тогда оно скакать перестает, когда полоска прокрутки исчезает при отображении fancybox. Вот тут https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/360 баг обсуждался, но кажется ни к чему так и не пришли, хотя там разные предложения есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".popap").fancybox({
    fixed : false,
    autoCenter : true
});
```

Вот еще один [способ](http://jsfiddle.net/mqj2xw9z/1/):

```js
jQuery(".modalbox").fancybox({
  fixed: false,
  autoCenter: true
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
.modalbox {
  margin-top: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.fixed {
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">fixed div</div>


<a href="#modal-order" class="modalbox">Заказать обратный звонок</a>

<div id="modal-order" class="modal">
  Modal
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman) спасибо за подсказку!

> Если фиксированному блоку вместо width: 100%; задать точную ширину экран, тогда оно скакать перестает, когда полоска прокрутки исчезает при отображении fancybox.Воттут github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/360 баг обсуждался, но кажется ни к чему так и не пришли, хотя там разные предложения есть. – Visman

Действительно, растянуть на всю ширину можно и вот так.

```css
#menu {
   width: 100vw;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 99;
}
```